# <C-S> mapping in Vim terminal issues

Tags: mapping, vim

I am having issues trying to map `<C-S>` in Vim terminal.

The same mapping works in MacVim/gVim but not in the terminal. I have tried the below mappings in Terminal.app and the latest version of iterm2 and it fails to work.

Is using `<C-S>` a bad idea because of terminal issues? If it is I was not aware (and could not find any information about it.

```
nnoremap <script> <buffer><C-s> :call <sid>MyPrivateFunction()<CR>
```

Note though that the above mapping *works* in MacVim/gVim but not in the terminal.

I have also tried the following variations:

```
cmap <script> <buffer><C-s> call <sid>MyPrivateFunction()<CR>
map <script> <buffer><C-s> :call <sid>MyPrivateFunction()<CR>
nnoremap <C-s> :call MyFunction()<CR>
```

Am I doing something wrong? And again, is it a bad idea to issue such a mapping? What would be the alternative?

Comment: Heads up — consider checking out [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) as a replacement to Terminal. I switched two months ago, and it's a much better piece of software (256 colors, split windows, full screen, autocomplete, etc).

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, I do use iTerm2, but I also tried Terminal.app to make sure it was not a terminal emulator problem.

Comment: Haha, my fault, I completely skipped over that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<C-s> and <C-q> have been used for decades to do [software flow control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_flow_control).  You'll probably want to avoid mapping those key sequences in general.

Comment: ok, so <S-s> it is then. It is odd that it is not explicitly warned somewhere in Vim's awesome docs :(

Comment: @alfredodeza: I expect it's not mentioned simply because it's not universally a bad idea.  As you noted on Mac, for instance, it's perfectly acceptable.  And the [Cream customization](http://cream.sourceforge.net/) for vim explicitly maps C-s to save, like most desktop editors.  It's just one of those odd remnants from terminal emulation long ago.